# having issues with Error Number: 1064

Tags: codeigniter

Any time I try to access a page I created it says:

> Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

```
SELECT * FROM (`_db_tb_article`) WHERE `article_id` =
```

> Filename:
>
> ```
> C:\xampp\htdocs\gtech\__ghtec__$y$tem__core\database\DB_driver.php
> ```
>
> Line Number:
>
> ```
> 330
> ```

this is my model

```
<?php

class article_model extends CI_Model {


function add()
{
     $this->db->insert('article',$_POST);
     if($this->db->_error_number()){
         return $this->db->_error_number();
     }
}

function update($article_id, $data_fields = NULL){
     if($data_fields == NULL){
        $this->db->where("article_id =".$article_id);
        $this->db->update('article',$_POST);
     }else{
        $this->db->where("article_id =".$article_id);
        $this->db->update('article',$data_fields);
    }

    $is_error = $this->db->_error_number();
    if($is_error){
       echo $is_error;
    }

   return TRUE;
}

function delete($id){
     $this->db->where("article_id =".$id);
      return $this->db->delete('article');
}

//return the article with this id
function get_article($id){
    $this->db->where("article_id =".$id);
    $query = $this->db->get('article');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
       return $query->row_array();
   }
   else {
     echo $this->db->_error_message();
     return FALSE;
   }
}

//return the available article in the table
function get_article_all(){

    $query = $this->db->get('article');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
       foreach($query->result() as $row){
           $result[]    =   $row;
       }
       return $result;
   }
}

}
```

I have checked the line 330 and can't seem to find a way to solve that problem... I need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your where statement

**function update**

```
$this->db->where("article_id =".$article_id);
```

Should Be

```
$this->db->where('article_id', $article_id);
```

**function get_article**

```
$this->db->where("article_id =".$id);
```

Should Be

```
$this->db->where('article_id', $id);
```

**function Delete**

```
$this->db->where("article_id =".$id);
```

Should Be

```
$this->db->where('article_id', $id);
```

Comment: thanks man, can't believe that was the source of my headache... thanks again

Comment: thanks, but now i have another problem @wolfgang1983, anytime i go to the view and click the link pathed to the add function it just refreshes the page... i made the link something like...
<div style="float:right"><a href="javascript:load_content('index.php/article/add')"> Add</a></div>
what should I do to solve that....

Comment: That is a different issue to your main post. Open another question I would recommend.